# Webpack not compiling JS and SCSS files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass, compiler-errors

I'm struggling to get my JS and my SCSS files to compile using webpack. npm run dev is working and is watching the files by the looks of it, but it's not creating my scripts.min.js and styles.min.css within my wordpress theme. I have tried to create the files but still not writing to them.

Any help would be appreciated.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --watch --mode=development",
    "prod": "webpack --watch --mode=production",
    "build": "webpack"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "form-serialize": "^0.7.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.4",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^5.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.19.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack-fix-style-only-entries": "0.0.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0"
}
```

webpack.config

```
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const postcssPresetEnv = require("postcss-preset-env");
const FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin = require("webpack-fix-style-only-entries");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "scripts.min": "./src/js/app.js",
    "styles.min": "./src/scss/styles.scss"
  },
 output: {
   path: path.resolve(
       __dirname,
       "../public/wp-content/themes/scotts-of-thrapston/dist/js"
   )
 },
 module: {
   rules: [
     // Babel
     {
       test: /\.js$/,
       exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
       use: {
         loader: "babel-loader",
         options: {
           presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
         }
       }
     },

     // Styles
     {
       test: /\.scss$/,
       use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
         fallback: "style-loader",
         use: [
           {
             loader: "css-loader",
             options: {
               url: false,
               minimize: true,
               sourceMap: true
             }
           },
           {
             loader: "postcss-loader",
             options: {
               ident: "postcss",
               plugins: [
                 postcssPresetEnv({
                   stage: 3,
                   browsers: "last 2 versions"
                 })
               ],
               sourceMap: true
             }
           },
           {
             loader: "sass-loader",
             options: {
               sourceMap: true
             }
           }
         ]
       })
     }
   ]
 },
 plugins: [
   new FixStyleOnlyEntriesPlugin(),
   new ExtractTextPlugin({
     filename: "../css/[name].css",
     allChunks: true
   })
 ]
};
```

**npm run dev log:**

```
webpack is watching the files…

webpack-fix-style-only-entries: removing js from style only module: styles.min.js
Hash: 7e78c7655d479eb7c2e7
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 2046ms
Built at: 05/06/2021 03:51:58
Asset      Size       Chunks             Chunk Names
../css/styles.min.css  20 bytes   styles.min  [emitted]  styles.min
scripts.min.js  3.79 KiB  scripts.min  [emitted]  scripts.min
Entrypoint scripts.min = scripts.min.js
Entrypoint styles.min = ../css/styles.min.css
[./src/js/app.js] 13 bytes {scripts.min} [built]
[./src/scss/styles.scss] 41 bytes {styles.min} [built]
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--5-2!node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??postcss!node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-4!src/scss/sty
les.scss:
Entrypoint undefined = extract-text-webpack-plugin-output-filename
[./node_modules/css-loader/index.js?!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./src/scss/styles.scss] ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./no
de_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-4!./src/scss/styles.scss 519 bytes {0} [built]
+ 1 hidden module
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: updated post with log when running npm run dev